# How to automatically simulate the top-level VHDL entity with ModelSim?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

When calling the `vsim` command, how can I make ModelSim automatically use the top-level VHDL entity (or entities)? I'm writing a generic script for running VHDL simulations.

Currently I'm doing the following to compile and simulate:

```
vcom design.vhd testbench.vhd
vsim -c -do "onElabError resume; run -all; exit" MY_TB
```

How can I make it so that ModelSim automatically simulates `MY_TB` without explicitly specifying it.

Automatically using the top-level module(s) is possible with Verilog:

```
vlog -writetoplevels my.tops design.v testbench.v
vsim -c -do "onElabError resume; run -all; exit" -f my.tops
```

Answer (score 1):

My way was to create a script in Ruby. It's very easy to find the entity/architecture names and then invoke Modelsim. The outline of the solution is:

1. Open the VHDL file: 
   `file_contents = File.read(file_name)`
2. Use a regular expression to find the entity and architecture names:
   `match = file_contents.match(/entity (.*) is/)`
   `entity = match && match[1]`
   `match = file_contents.match(/architecture (.*) of/)`
   `architecture = match && match[1]`
3. Invoke Modelsim in command-line mode:
   `vsim -do {run -all; quit} -lib /temp/work -c entity_name(architecture_name)`

I've included my entire script below for reference. I think its highlights are:

- `vhdl -m` → "make" project by compiling all VHDL files in the directory
- `vhdl -f text` → find `text` in VHDL files
- `vhdl -s filename` → simulate `filename`

  ```
  # vhdl.rb: Swiss army knife for VHDL-related tasks.
  #   vhdl --compile file_name     # Compile file with ModelSim
  #   vhdl --simulate file_name    # Simulate file with ModelSim
  #   vhdl --find text             # Find text in VHDL source files
  #   vhdl --make dir              # Compile all files in dir

  require 'optparse'
  require 'pathname'

  begin
    gem 'colorize' # gem install colorize
    require 'colorize'
  rescue Gem::LoadError
    puts "Gem 'colorize' is not installed. You can install it by typing:\ngem install colorize"
  end

  WORK = Pathname.new("/temp/work")

  def ensure_library_work_exists
    if WORK.exist?
      puts "Found library work at #{WORK.expand_path}"
    else
      puts "Creating library work at #{WORK.expand_path}..."
      system('mkdir \temp\work')
      system('vlib /temp/work')
    end
  end 

  def compile(file_name)
    ensure_library_work_exists
    puts "Compiling #{file_name}..."
    puts cmd_line = "vcom -2008 -work #{WORK} #{file_name}"
    system(cmd_line)
  end

  def simulate(file_name)
    ensure_library_work_exists
    puts "Simulating #{file_name}..."
    compile(file_name)
    entity, architecture = find_entity_architecture(file_name)
    if entity && architecture
      cmd_line = "vsim -lib #{WORK} -c #{$entity || entity}(#{$architecture || architecture}) -do \"run -all; quit\""
      system(cmd_line)
    end 
  end

  def find_entity_architecture(file_name)
    file_contents = File.read(file_name)

    match = file_contents.match(/entity (.*) is/)
    entity = match && match[1]

    match = file_contents.match(/architecture (.*) of/)
    architecture = match && match[1]

    [ entity, architecture ]
  end

  def find_text(text)
    puts cmd_line = "findstr /sni /C:\"#{text}\" *.vhd *.vhdl"
    system(cmd_line)
  end

  $before_context = 1
  $after_context = 3

  def find_filenames(path)
    filenames = Dir["#{path}/**/*.vhd"]
    puts "Found #{filenames.count} VHDL files"
    filenames
  end

  def grep_text(text)
    filenames = find_filenames(".")
    filenames.each do |filename|
      output = `grep #{text} #{filename} --recursive --line-number --before-context=#{$before_context} --after-context=#{$after_context}`
      last_output_was_blank = true
      if output.empty?
        print ".".green
        last_output_was_blank = true
      else
        puts() if last_output_was_blank
        puts filename.green, output
        last_output_was_blank = false
      end
    end
  end

  def compile_vhdl_file(file_name)
    vcom_output = `vcom -2008 -work #{WORK} #{file_name}`
    if vcom_output.match(/\*\* Error/)
      error_message = vcom_output[/(\*\* Error.*$)/m]
      raise error_message
    end
    puts vcom_output
  end

  def make(path)
    ensure_library_work_exists
    filenames = Dir["#{path}/**/*.vhd"]
    puts "Found #{filenames.count} VHDL files:"
    puts filenames.join(" ").green

    pass_number = 0  
    failed_filenames = []
    begin
      pending_files_count = filenames.count - failed_filenames.count
      puts ">>> Starting pass #{pass_number} -- pending #{pending_files_count}, failed #{failed_filenames.count}".yellow 
      previously_failed_filenames = failed_filenames.dup
      failed_filenames.clear
      filenames.each do |filename|
        begin
          compile_vhdl_file(filename)
        rescue
          puts "#{$!}".red
          failed_filenames << filename
        end
      end
      pass_number += 1
    end while failed_filenames.any? and (failed_filenames != previously_failed_filenames)

    if failed_filenames.any?
      puts "*** Error: Failed to compile:".red
      puts failed_filenames.join("\n").red
      exit
    end
  end

  OptionParser.new do |o|
    o.on('-e', '--ent entity_name') { |entity| $entity = entity }
    o.on('-a', '--arch architecture_name') { |architecture| $architecture = architecture }
    o.on('-c', '--compile file') { |file| compile(file) }
    o.on('-s', '--simulate file') { |file| simulate(file) }
    o.on('-f', '--find text') { |text| find_text(text) }
    o.on('-b', '--before-context before_context') { |lines_count| $before_context = lines_count }
    o.on('-t', '--after-context after_context') { |lines_count| $after_context = lines_count }
    o.on('-g', '--grep text') { |text| grep_text(text) }
    o.on('-m', '--make [dir]') { |dir| make(dir || '.') }
    o.parse!
  end
  ```

Comment: The script simulates one file if you call it with `vhdl -s filename.vhd`. It compiles all files in the directory if you call it with `vhdl -m`. IMO, it doesn't make much sense to simulate many files at once, unless you want to run a set of testbenches. In that case, I have another script that simulates all VHDL files whose names end with `_tb.vhd`.